# Too Many Redirects in ServicePreAction Hook

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay Portal 6.0. version. I am creating hooks plugin for redirecting to new community whenever user request. I have overridden run method in ServicePreAction like this:

```java
protected void doRun(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(
          WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY); 

    if(some condition) {
        response.sendRedirect("/web/mycommunity/home");
    }
}
```

But i am geting "Too Many Redirects" Error.
Any solution?

Comment: What is "some condition". Are you sure "some condition" is not true in /web/mycommunity/home page?

Comment: Some condition might be, String a ="test", if(a.equals("test")) { }... :)

Comment: no plm with some condition. some condition will always true.